# Duplicate Materials with separate animation keyframes

Tags: materials, keyframes, linked-data

How can I create a duplicate of a material with separate animation keyframes? I want to create two objects, both with the same material properties, but that fade in at different times. However, every method I've tried of copying or duplicating the materials causes the keyframes to be linked together, so when I change the keyframes of one material, it changes the other too. How do I unlink the keyframes so I can fade them in at different times?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141438/material-duplicate-then-unlink-material-from-original

The answer there does not help me, since I have no idea how to use the NLA.

Comment: I'm not sure material actions work like other actions, it would be good to have material actions aligned with all other sorts of action

Comment: Found the answer: https://developer.blender.org/T54177

> In the outliner, type "Animation", then right click on the object's animation data you want to remove and click "Clear Animation Data"; or just hit Spacebar and type "Clear Animation".